# BootStrap navbar not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was working on the tutorial to build a simple website, when I tried running the bootstrap template, it does not seem to show up

[The screenshot of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRTaK.png)

I've included the bootstrap.js file as well as the jquery, here's my code to take a look at:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src ="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Kevo's Website</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <p>This is the welcome page</p>
    </div>

</div><!-- /.container -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks fine to me. As Jason mentioned, I think your local bootstrap file isn't being called correctly.

```css
.row {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Kevo's Website</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>This is the welcome page</p>
  </div>

</div><!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: Loading from a CDN like this is almost always the best approach.  The only downside is you must be connected to the internet to work on this page as the resources are remotely hosted.

Comment: Yeah, I think the file I downloaded corrupted then, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From your screenshot, I would guess that `/css/bootstrap.css` is returning a 404, or you are using the browser's ability to load HTML from the file system (by double clicking on your index.html file) in which case the reference `/css/bootstrap.css` is looking for a folder on your root drive with the path `/css/bootstrap.css`.  If you have the css file int he same folder just drop the `/css/` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your css/boostrap is not linked correctly, if your doing this on your local machine try `view source` and click the css path if its there. and jquery and boostrap.js must be place before the body tags ends.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Kevo's Website</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <p>This is the welcome page</p>
    </div>

</div><!-- /.container -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```